# Python - Unable to write a relatively long string to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm scraping some data from a website and storing information into a list of lists. Each of the lists consists of 9 string elements of which 8 are rather short (max 30 characters). But the last element of each list is a relatively long string consisting of over 200 characters in length and can vary up to 1000. When I try to write each list into a csv file they all get written without a problem except for the last element. Due to my lack of knowledge I'd guess the problem is in the last element's length, but I have no way of proving it.

When I print out a single list in the terminal, I get an output like this:

```
['BSM Crew Service Centre – Croatia', 'http://maritime-connector.com/company/bsm-crew-service-centre-croatia/147/', 'C/E', 'http://maritime-connector.com/job/bsm-crew-service-centre-croatia-ce-3513/', 'Engine', 'Container ship', 'Worldwide', '19.12.201', '\nContract: 4 months onboard\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWith a fleet of approximately 650 vessels under full and crew management we offer excellent career opportunities and steady employment for professional, capable and ambitious people onboard and onshore. Recognizing that people will always be our most valuable asset, we concentrate not only on recruitment and training, but also on maintaining highly motivated staff in every position. The key here is a long-term approach based on excellent human resources practices. Our tough but fair selection procedures, periodic appraisals, performance-based incentives, timely payments and opportunities for development all play a crucial role in maintaining an excellent pool of dedicated office personnel and seafarers all around the world\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

The last element gets omitted completely when being written into the csv file. I've thought of trying to write the lists into another type of file instead of csv, but I have no information about the alternatives.

My code for writing it into a csv file looks like this:

```
with open('Job-Listing.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outputCSV:
        jobListingCSV = csv.writer(outputCSV, dialect = 'excel', \
                                   lineterminator = '\n', \
                                   delimiter = ';')
        for post in self.JobPost:
        # self.JobPost is a collection of lists (post) which contain strings
            jobListingCSV.writerow(post)
```

I don't see what the problem could be. I've tried playing with the encoding as maybe the '\n' and '\t' characters cause the csv writer maybe to skip the last element of each list, but I didn't have any success.

Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example:

```
import csv

JobPost =[['BSM Crew Service Centre – Croatia', 'http://maritime-connector.com/company/bsm-crew-service-centre-croatia/147/', 'C/E', 'http://maritime-connector.com/job/bsm-crew-service-centre-croatia-ce-3513/', 'Engine', 'Container ship', 'Worldwide', '19.12.201', '\nContract: 4 months onboard\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWith a fleet of approximately 650 vessels under full and crew management we offer excellent career opportunities and steady employment for professional, capable and ambitious people onboard and onshore. Recognizing that people will always be our most valuable asset, we concentrate not only on recruitment and training, but also on maintaining highly motivated staff in every position. The key here is a long-term approach based on excellent human resources practices. Our tough but fair selection procedures, periodic appraisals, performance-based incentives, timely payments and opportunities for development all play a crucial role in maintaining an excellent pool of dedicated office personnel and seafarers all around the world\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'],['Columbia Shipmanagement Rijeka', 'http://maritime-connector.com/company/columbia-shipmanagement-rijeka/1251/', '1 x CHIEF ENGINEER FOR HEAVY LIFT VESSEL', 'http://maritime-connector.com/job/columbia-shipmanagement-rijeka-1-x-chief-engineer-for-heavy-lift-vessel-3769/', 'Engine', 'Heavy lift vessel', '', '07.09.201', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWe are looking for the Chief Engineer for heavy lift vessel.\r\nEngine: Sulzer 7RT- flex50 11620kW\r\n\r\nFor more info please contact Columbia Shipmanagement Rijeka d.o.o. – www.csmhr.com\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t']]
with open('Job-Listing2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outputCSV:
        jobListingCSV = csv.writer(outputCSV, dialect = 'excel', \
                                   lineterminator = '\n', \
                                   delimiter = ';')

        for post in JobPost:
            jobListingCSV.writerow(post)
```

Comment: `jobListingCSV.write(''.join(self.JobPost))`?

Comment: I would drop `lineterminator = '\n'` and use `newline=""` in `open` call (python 3) for starters. Also `dialect` can be dropped. Start simple. There's no reason why it wouldn't work. Can you provide a small [mcve] with input (as list) and output (as file) ?

Comment: I've just tried dropping the `dialect`, and chaning the `lineterminator = '\n'` to `newline=""` and I get a TypeError: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: I'll try to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example now.

Comment: Jean-François is suggesting to pass `newline=""` to the `open` call, not to `csv.writer`.

Comment: Do you really need to keep all those tabs, newlines and returns in the final string? It might be an idea to strip them out; at least, get rid of the ones at the start and end of the string, using the `.strip()` method.

Comment: Just tried putting the `newline=""` into the `open` call, and still the string is not being written. The tabs and newlines are not necessary, but if possible I would like that the string is kept formatted nicely.

Comment: without a [mcve] we can just guess (and my guess skills are low today)

Comment: I've edited a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example in the question.

Comment: "When I print out a single list in the terminal, I get an output like this:": is this list the input? in that case we don't need all those web scraping code. Just the input & the csv write code. that's what we mean by [mcve]

Comment: You're right. Corrected.

Comment: @917k if you look at the file - you'll see the last element is there... it's just that you've got actual newlines inside the column so they're being quoted and wrapped onto new lines... it's all there... depending what you open the CSV file in though - it may not like that.

Comment: Didn't think it would be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't view the written cell fully, so I completely missed the written information due to the newlines inside the column.